# Is there a way to Add TICKS/Labels in RangeSlider for Plotly (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js

I have a line chart that uses Range slider and I want to just add some ticks/labels below the range slider. I've search PLOTLY docs but couldn't seem to find a parameter to imply ticks to the chart. Any insights?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

With the regular slider, we can set a label to each of the defined [`steps`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-sliders-items-slider-steps-items-step-label), but it seems there is no possibility to do the same with the [rangeslider](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-rangeslider).

---

**Python**

You can use the `marks` property to set labels (and optionally add styles or even restrict which values can be selected), eg. :

```
dcc.RangeSlider(
    min=min,
    max=max,
    step=1,
    marks={ m: str(m) for m in range(min, max+1) },
    value=[min, max]
)
```

Note :

> If slider marks are defined and step is set to `None`
> then the slider will only be able to select values that have been
> predefined by the marks. Note that the default is `step=1`, so you must
> explicitly specify `None` to get this behavior.

@see [Marks and Steps](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/rangeslider#marks-and-steps)

Comment: Thank you very much Eric, Although i think this options does not exist in Plotly's javascript. I tried adding in marks and step but it doesn't affect the chart

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realize it was for javascript ! Anyway I made some checks and it appears that we can't simply do the same in js.

Comment: Thank you very much @Eric.  Atleast I now have another set of eye that confirms it isn't available out of the box. Im not going crazy hehe thanks!